# chrome - close browser but keep tabs synced to different device

Tags: google-chrome, browser, sync, browser-tabs, cross-platform

So I recently fought down my anti-data-exposure reflex and logged myself in to Google Chrome to sync browser data.

The idea is to be able to look at stuff on Linux, reboot the device into Windows and have the very same tabs open in Chrome (or vice-versa).

Or maybe shut down my laptop and continue on my desktop.

Supposedly, this is supported, as hinted to by the "advanced sync settings" where you can choose to sync "open tabs".

But I can't for the love of me figure out how to close chrome without closing the tabs so this kind of sync can happen.

How do I do this?

Comment: What I do to keep the tabs open, is to turn off the computer when chrome is still opened, and then it's available on my android device. Helps?